# Docker build in dind not producing the same result as local docker build

Tags: docker, meteor, gitlab, gitlab-ci, docker-in-docker

I have been trying to set up a gitlab ci using shared runners. My .gitlab-ci.yml looks like this:

```
image: docker:latest

# When using dind, it's wise to use the overlayfs driver for
# improved performance.
variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  GCP_PROJECT_ID: example-12345
  IMAGE_NAME: test

services:
- docker:dind

stages:
  - publish

publish-image:
  stage: publish
  script:
    # Create our image. Expected to create an image 'image_id'
    - docker build -t $IMAGE_NAME .
    # Tag our image for container registry
    - docker tag $IMAGE_NAME eu.gcr.io/$GCP_PROJECT_ID/$IMAGE_NAME
    # Install CA certs, openssl to https downloads, python for gcloud sdk
    - apk add --update make ca-certificates openssl python
    - update-ca-certificates
    # Download and install Google Cloud SDK
    - wget https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz
    - tar zxvf google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz && ./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh --usage-reporting=false --path-update=true
    - google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud --quiet components install kubectl
    - google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud --quiet components update
    - google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file g.json
    # Optionally tag the image with the commit short-sha
    - docker tag $IMAGE_NAME eu.gcr.io/$GCP_PROJECT_ID/$IMAGE_NAME:$(echo $CI_COMMIT_SHA | cut -c1-8)
    #- google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud docker -- push eu.gcr.io/$GCP_PROJECT_ID/$IMAGE_NAME:latest
    - google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud docker -- push eu.gcr.io/$GCP_PROJECT_ID/$IMAGE_NAME:$(echo $CI_COMMIT_SHA | cut -c1-8)
  # Only run builds for these refs
  only:
    - master
```

The project I am trying to build is Meteor application (Meteor version 1.6.1) thats supposed to be run in a kubernetes cluster. For creating containers I am using https://github.com/jshimko/meteor-launchpad.
When I use docker build on my local machine everything is working, but when in the CI I get this error (after build in stage `Running npm install in the server bundle...`):

```
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

module.js:540
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/meteor/dist/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp:15:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bcrypt@1.0.3 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@1.0.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-03-08T13_29_09_532Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! meteor-dev-bundle@ install: `node npm-rebuild.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the meteor-dev-bundle@ install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-03-08T13_29_09_574Z-debug.log
```

But I dont believe it is an actual meteor problem since I know the code works.
Another weird thing is that the build actually is successful in an older version of the code running meteor 1.5.2.2 (New version is 1.6.1), however it then breaks when run in kubernetes. The error from the pod reads:

```
=> Starting app on port 3000...
## There is an issue with `node-fibers` ##
`/opt/meteor/dist/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/bin/linux-x64-57/fibers.node` is missing.

Try running this to fix the issue: /opt/nodejs/bin/node /opt/meteor/dist/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/build
/opt/meteor/dist/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/fibers.js:20
        throw new Error('Missing binary. See message above.');
        ^

Error: Missing binary. See message above.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/meteor/dist/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/fibers.js:20:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
```

Dispite the build log from the runner states:

```
> fibers@1.0.15 install /opt/meteor/dist/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers
> node build.js || nodejs build.js

`linux-x64-46` exists; testing
Binary is fine; exiting
```

Since I know that the build can succeed I assume that the docker-in-docker is run with the right settings on the shared runners. Either by binding the outer docker socket to the inner och by running privileged (As described [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-in-docker-executor) and [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-socket-binding))

So why do my build get corrupted/fail on the CI?

EDIT: My local builds are done on ubuntu 16